# how to call form name dynamically react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to call dynamic form e.g  (this is static need to replace by dynamic) <{this.data.formname}/>

so it will call that particular model form.

React js

Comment: Hi! Please re-take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your form name into variable with a capital letter like

`let MyForm = this.data.formname`

And then in the return of your render function :

`<MyForm>...</MyForm>`

Comment: not working done this let MyForm = this.props.data.action; In return method => <MyForm />

Comment: Read this: https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9 it's what you're looking for